# How do I make a random function for a Point class in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am brand new to Perl (just started reading about it today), and I'm trying to make a `Point` class. I can get it to set and get `x` or `y`, but I'm wanting to make a function called `random` and when it is called on it computes a random `x` and `y` and then sets `x` and `y`. What I am doing is not working. What do I need to do? I'm going off a tutorial from tutorialspoint and the example they used is a person. So if this is not normal Perl code style that is why.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#class name 
package Point;

#constructor
sub new
{       
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub getX{
    my($self) = @_;
    return $self->{_x};
}

sub getY{
    my($self)= @_;
    return $self->{_y};

}

sub setX{
    my ($self, $x) = @_;
    $self->{_x} = $x if defined($x);
    return $self->{_x};
}
sub setY{
    my ($self, $y) = @_;
    $self->{_y} = $y if defined($y);
    return $self->{_y};
}
sub random{
    my $range = 50;
    my $randomX = int(rand($range));
    my $randomY = int(rand($range));

    my $self->{_x} = $randomX;
    my $self->{_y} = $randomY;

    return $self->{_x}, $self->{_y};
}
1;
```

Comment: "What I am doing is not working." `<--` What does that mean?

Comment: The code I have in my random function is not working.

Comment: Repeating the same thing is not helpful. In what way is it not working? What do you expect it to do? What is it actually doing? What have you done so far to fix it?

Comment: Like I said, I just started reading about perl. I would love to tell you what is wrong and where I'm going wrong. But I don't know where to start. According to my tests, getX, getY, setX, and setY all work. Like I also stated, "but I'm wanting to make a function called random and when it is called on it computes a random x and y and then sets x and y." To answer your second question, it seems as though all the function does is assign x's value to y and y's value to x. Your third question, I have tried reading more about it on tutorials point and figured a nice person would help me

Comment: on stack overflow, since it is a very beginner question. But, as it sometimes is on here, has already been a pain to ask.

Comment: Please slow down with things like "_nice person_" and "_pain_".   The main purpose of SO is to answer fairly specific questions about a particular problem.  It is difficult to deal with rounded questions where the very basics are missing, since they mostly require a mini-tutorial.  Yours fits somewhere in between, in my opinion.  (That you for showing your code though!)

Comment: What I was getting at is that I could tell your code wouldn't compile just from looking at it, and the error messages it was outputting would have gone a long way toward making this a good question. See: [mcve]

Comment: Asking a question with a concrete problem statement is great. Asking people to debug your code for you is not so great.

Comment: One specific remark.  Why not create and initialize the data when an object is constructed?  What you have now will have a problem if you call `getX()` first, since there is no `$self->{_x}` to read off.  An object should be ready to go once it is constructed. A simple way: when you declare `$self` in `new`, set it up with keys and values.  The initial values can be passed in when `new` is called, and if not pick reasonable defaults.  For example, `my ($class, $x, $y) = @_;`, then check whether they have values and set defaults if not, then `my $self = { _x = $x, _y = $y };`

Comment: What I meant above is that the object can be made either with `my $pt = Point->new(1,2)` (and have x,y of `$pt` be 1,2), or with `my $pt = Point->new()`. In this second case the `$x,$y` in `new` are undefined and when you check for that you can give them default values, say zeroes.  So `Point->new()` creates a point at `(0,0)`.

Comment: Oh, that was meant to be `my $self = { _x => $x, _y => $y };`

Comment: Thanks @zdim. I added that to this and my other program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to re-declare `$self` by putting `my` before it:

```
my $self->{_x} = $randomX;
my $self->{_y} = $randomY;
```

In fact, you should have gotten a warning about that:

> "my" variable $self masks earlier declaration in same scope

After fixing that warning, you'd get the following error:

> Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name (did you forget
>   to declare "my $self"?)

That's because methods receive an instance of the class as their first parameter, but you're not assigning it:

```
my $self = shift;
```

Putting it all together, we have the following changes:

```
sub random {
    my $self = shift;
    my $range = 50;
    $self->{_x} = int(rand($range));
    $self->{_y} = int(rand($range));

    return ($self->{_x}, $self->{_y});
}
```

Testing:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $p = Point->new;
print Dumper($p->random);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = 23;
$VAR2 = 49;
```

Comment: ""my" variable $self masks earlier declaration in same scope" I remember coming across that error at one point. Now it makes sense. I appreciate it.

Comment: random would make more sense as a class method to me (an alternate constructor).  I can't tell if that's what the roman gentleperson actually wants or not.

Comment: @ysth I don't disagree with you, but that feels like a code review to me. I only tried to answer the specific question of why it wasn't working.